# How to create new columns in dataframe using Spark Scala based on different string patterns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Step 1: I created a Dataframe df with two columns 'COLUMN A' and 'COLUMN B' of type string.

Step 2: I have created new columns from 'COLUMN B' based on their Index positions.

My Requirement: I need one more column a6 to be created NOT on index position but by anything which matches yyy or xxx or yyy or zzz in the string

```
val extractedDF = df
      .withColumn("a1", regexp_extract($"_raw", "\\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\]",2))
      .withColumn("a2", regexp_extract($"_raw", "\\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\]",3))
      .withColumn("a3", regexp_extract($"_raw", "\\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\]",5))
      .withColumn("a4", regexp_extract($"_raw", "(?<=uvwx: )(.*?)(?=,)",1))
      .withColumn("a5", regexp_extract($"_raw", "\\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\]",13))
```

Please help me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regexp_replace() and provide xxx|yyy|zzz as alternations

```
scala> val df = Seq(("abcdef"),("axxx"),("byyypp"),("czzzr")).toDF("_raw")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_raw: string]

scala> df.show(false)
+------+
|_raw  |
+------+
|abcdef|
|axxx  |
|byyypp|
|czzzr |
+------+


scala>  df.withColumn("a6",regexp_replace($"_raw",""".*(xxx|yyy|zzz).*""","OK")===lit("OK")).show(false)
+------+-----+
|_raw  |a6   |
+------+-----+
|abcdef|false|
|axxx  |true |
|byyypp|true |
|czzzr |true |
+------+-----+


scala>
```

If you want to extract the match, then

```
scala> df.withColumn("a6",regexp_extract($"_raw",""".*(xxx|yyy|zzz).*""",1)).show(false)
+------+---+
|_raw  |a6 |
+------+---+
|abcdef|   |
|axxx  |xxx|
|byyypp|yyy|
|czzzr |zzz|
+------+---+


scala>
```

***EDIT1:***

```
scala> val df = Seq((""" [2019-03-18T02:13:20.988-05:00] [svc4_prod2_bpel_ms14] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.soa.mediator.serviceEngine] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '57' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 7e05e8d3-8d20-475f-a414-cb3295151c3e-0054c6b8,1:84559] [APP: soa-infra] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] [oracle.soa.tracking.FlowId: 14436421] [oracle.soa.tracking.InstanceId: 363460793] [oracle.soa.tracking.SCAEntityId: 50139] [composite_name: DFOLOutputRouting] """)).toDF("_raw")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_raw: string]

scala> df.withColumn("a6",regexp_extract($"_raw",""".*(composite_name|compositename|composites|componentDN):\s+(\S+)\]""",2)).select("a6").show(false)
+-----------------+
|a6               |
+-----------------+
|DFOLOutputRouting|
+-----------------+


scala>
```

***EDIT2***

```
scala> val df = Seq((""" [2019-03-18T02:13:20.988-05:00] [svc4_prod2_bpel_ms14] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.soa.mediator.serviceEngine] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '57' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 7e05e8d3-8d20-475f-a414-cb3295151c3e-0054c6b8,1:84559] [APP: soa-infra] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] [oracle.soa.tracking.FlowId: 14436421] [oracle.soa.tracking.InstanceId: 363460793] [oracle.soa.tracking.SCAEntityId: 50139] [composite_name: DFOLOutputRouting!3.20.0202.190103.1116_19] """)).toDF("_raw")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_raw: string]

scala> df.withColumn("a6",regexp_extract($"_raw",""".*(composite_name|compositename|composites|componentDN):\s+([a-zA-Z]+)""",2)).select("a6").show(false)
+-----------------+
|a6               |
+-----------------+
|DFOLOutputRouting|
+-----------------+


scala>
```

Comment: @RaheemMohammad.. could you please share some sample data and expected output?.

Comment: [2019-03-18T02:13:20.988-05:00] [svc4_prod2_bpel_ms14] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.soa.mediator.serviceEngine] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '57' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 7e05e8d3-8d20-475f-a414-cb3295151c3e-0054c6b8,1:84559] [APP: soa-infra] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] [oracle.soa.tracking.FlowId: 14436421] [oracle.soa.tracking.InstanceId: 363460793] [oracle.soa.tracking.SCAEntityId: 50139] [composite_name: DFOLOutputRouting]

I am looking at composite_name value "DFOLOutputRouting"

Comment: did you get chance to look in?

Comment: Could you please add the input and the required output in the question... I'm not quite understanding it from your comments..

Comment: Comment#3 is my input data
Output Needed: I I am trying to pull values associated with anything which matches name i.e composite_name or compositename or composites or componentDN from above input file. So here i am looking to extract DFOLOutputRouting
[composite_name: DFOLOutputRouting]

Comment: is it clear for you now?? i desperately need help on this

Comment: Yes it worked @stack0114106
i have some events as DFOLOutputRouting!3.20.0202.190103.1116_19
is there a way where i can where i can ignore "!3.20.0202.190103.1116_19" and just get "DFOLOutputRouting"

Comment: check my EDIT2.. you keep changing the question every time.. better learn some regex tutorials and fine tune the queries

Comment: I am very new Spark processing but i will definitely work on your suggestions going forward and APPRECIATE your help on this

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: at the beginning of the answer in left side.. a tick mark will be there in grey colour, just click that..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are only about to get the result which matches the above string,

you can make use of the below code:

df.withColumn("a6",col("colName").contains("yyy")|| col("colName").contains("xxx"))

Comment: i used your logic with contains API and i see "true" and not the match